# How to get my file back in 2.79 after saving with 2.80 series?

Tags: blend-files, versions

I was experimenting with a file in 2.8 and accidentally saved it.

When I opened it back in 2.79 I can't see my model. It disappeared with the error

> File written by newer Blender binary.

How can I get my model? I can see my model in 2.8 but nothing in 2.79. I tried to export it  in .obj, but I lost all my modifiers, material and camera setting.

[image: blender error message]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restore your file from a backup. Check whether there is still a `.blend1` or `.blend2` next to your `.blend`, or pick a backup from another source.

If you didn't make backups before using a Blender 2.80 beta, you'll probably have to manually restore by trying to copy-paste bits and pieces between 2.80 and 2.79.

Note that the download page said **Do not use in production nor save important files with it** for a good reason.

Comment: Its giving error widows cannot open the file https://imgur.com/gallery/D70Xk7a and when i select the program i cant find blender in that program list.

Comment: Just rename it to `.blend` or open the file directly from Blender.

Comment: i cant find the .blend1 file in the open file directly from blender

Comment: Disable the "filtering of files" button in the file browser.

Answer (score 2):

I find the easiest way to get an object back into 2.79 is to append the object. After starting 2.79 (a new file not after opening the 2.80 file), choose File->Append and select the object from the 2.80 file, this brings in the object, modifiers, mesh data, materials and animation.

Directly opening a 2.80 file with 2.79 fails to read object data, you will find the mesh, materials and action data is there.

After opening a 2.80 file in 2.79, add a new object, in the mesh properties change its mesh data to use the original mesh data. Materials are usually associated with the mesh, but if not you can find the material in the materials list. If you go to the action editor (mode of the dopesheet) you can also select the action associated with the original object. Actual object data will be lost, such as modifiers.

[image: mesh data]

As most addons are not working yet, we only have two export options in 2.80, collada and alembic. Both can export data that can then be imported in 2.79, when exporting you want to make sure modifiers are not applied so that you can re-create them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can still see your model in 2.8 you should be able to just append it over to your 2.79 file by opening it (in 2.79) and appending it as an object from the 2.8 version file.

Comment: I tried it. Nothing is appended