# Cannot open this file on Blender 2.79b, blender quit unexpectedly

Tags: import

When i open this file on 2.79b, the apps quit unexpectedly.

But when i try to open in 2.83, it can open normally

But my daughter want 2.79b for editing, she don't want the latest version..

hopefully someone can help me, maybe some trick to make it work

This is the file
http://download1821.mediafire.com/5zb63pnn3i4g/b2ucqkt3tgefl5l/RobloxRig_Woman.zip

Comment: Related: [Opening files from version 2.8 in 2.79](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82677/78972), [How to get my file back in 2.79 after saving with 2.80 Aplha 2?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119147/78972)

Comment: Hello :). Blender doesn't support backward compatibility. 2.8+ versions are also fundamentally different from 2.7 so any importing/appending might cause issues later.